# C# HttpClientタイムアウトの設定をしたいです

Tags: c#

エラーになる時とならない時があり、インターネット環境に基づくものだとわかりました。
タイムアウトの設定をしたいのですが、どのように行えばよろしいでしょうか？

```
static async Task DownloadImage(HttpClient httpClient, string uri, string path)
    {
        /// httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500000);
        using (var res = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
        using (var fileStream = File.Create(path))
        using (var httpStream = await res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            await httpStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }

    static async Task DownloadImage(string[] uris, string path)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            await Task.WhenAll(uris.Select((uri, i) => DownloadImage(httpClient, uri, string.Format("{0}{1}.jpg", path, i + 1))));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

漠然と「タイムアウトを設定したい」とされていますが何のタイムアウト、処理開始からレスポンスを返し始めるまでの時間なのか、レスポンス中のストールなのかなどなど、求めているものを具体的に表現する必要があると思います。

[HttpClient.Timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx)は

> 要求がタイムアウトするまでのミリ秒単位の待機時間。
>   既定値は 100,000 ミリ秒 (100 秒) です。
>   タスクの CancellationTokenSource を使用して個々の要求ごとに異なるタイムアウトを設定できます。

だそうです（わかりません）。

```
static async Task DownloadImage(HttpClient httpClient, string uri, string path) {
    using (var res = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    using (var fileStream = File.Create(path))
    using (var httpStream = await res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        await httpStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}

static async Task DownloadImage(string[] uris, string path) {
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500000) })
        await Task.WhenAll(uris.Select((uri, i) => DownloadImage(httpClient, uri, string.Format("{0}{1}.jpg", path, i + 1))));
}
```